# Configuring Azure Application Insights with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-application-insights, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to configure Alert Rules in Azure Application Insights. Is this something that can be done using Terraform or i have to do it through the portal?

I would like to be alerted on the below things :

1. Whenever the average available memory is less than 200 megabyte (Signal Type = Metrics)
2. Whenever the average process cpu is greater than 80  (Signal Type = Metrics)
3. Whenever the average server response time is greater than 5000 milliseconds  (Signal Type = Metrics)
4. Whenever the count of failed requests is greater than 5  (Signal Type = Metrics)
5. Failure Anomalies - prodstats-masterdata-sandbox (Signal Type = Smart Detector)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using terraform azurerm providers [azurerm_monitor_metric_alert](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert) and [azurerm_monitor_smart_detector_alert_rule](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_smart_detector_alert_rule).